# Observable transformation

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm very new to observables, this might be a silly question for others but I can't find a way to do it. How do I convert
`Observable<Array<T>>` where `T` is a TypeScript class with property `Id(string)` into an `Array<string>`? I want to convert the `Id` properties into a string array.

Comment: Can you refer to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467336/how-can-i-get-an-observer-of-an-input-value-in-child-component/44467942#44467942)

Comment: did you have a look to the `map` operator?

Comment: @Aravind thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that answers my question, though I'm getting some ideas from that.

Comment: Yes. That's why I referred you to that answer. can you update the code to the post

Comment: @Hitmands yes I'm currently looking into the map function but the concept is about array and not observable array or I'm completely missing something. The implementation should be like the map function I just can't figure it out yet since I'm also new to it. Pure c# dev here before :)

Comment: past relevant code with what you expect and what did you try, otherwise this question will be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do 2 things here:

1. Flatten all arrays from the source array into a single observable of `T`
2. Map each instance of `T` to `Id` property

You can use [`mergeAll`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/mergeall.html) to flatten the observable as you would use `reduce` on a normal JS array.

```
const source = Rx.Observable.of(
  [{ Id: '1' }, { Id: '2' }],
  [{ Id: '3' }, { Id: '4' }]
 );

const flattened = source.mergeAll();

flattened.subscribe(s => console.log(s));
// => {Id:'1'}, {Id:'2'}, {Id:'3'}, {Id:'4'}
```

You can then use [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) (as with a normal JS array) to extract the `Id` property

```
const mapped = flattened.map(s => s.Id);

mapped.subscribe(s => console.log(s))
// => '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

Pull it all into 1 statement and...

```
source
  .mergeAll()
  .map(s => s.Id)
  .subscribe(s => console.log(s))

// => '1', '2', '3', '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce operator that like on javascript array. RxJS reduce operator will operate on the whole stream when it is completed.

See the example:

```
 let data$ = new Rx.Subject();

 data$
    .reduce((acc, el) => {acc.push(...el); return acc;}, [])
    .subscribe(x=>console.log(x));

  data$.next([{id:'1'}, {id:'2'}]);
  data$.next([{id:'3'}, {id:'4'}]);
  data$.complete();
```