# Angular: How to subscribe to @Input changes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a angular component, which renders a html table using the provided object array.

I have implemented `OnChanges` to detect changes to the `@Input`, it doesn't seem to work though.

For testing, I'm using `setInterval` to add some data, but It's not getting reflected in the child component.

This it the code I have so far,

**ng-table.component.ts:**

```
export class NgTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() data: any[];

    private columns: string[];
    private rows: string[][];

    constructor() {
        this.columns = [];
        this.rows = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes);
        if (changes.data) {
            this.extractRowsAndColumns(this.data);
        }
    }

    extractRowsAndColumns(objArray: any[]): void {
        const colSet = new Set<string>();
        for (let i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
            const keys = Object.keys(objArray[i]);
            for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
                colSet.add(keys[j]);
            }
        }
        this.columns = Array.from(colSet);

        for (let i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
            const obj = objArray[i];
            const row = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < this.columns.length; j++) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(this.columns[j])) {
                    row.push(obj[this.columns[j]]);
                } else {
                    row.push(null);
                }
            }
            this.rows.push(row);
        }
    }
}
```

**ng-table.component.html:**

```
<div>
    <table class="ngtable">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
            <td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{cell}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm using the above component in app.component

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  timer: any;
  count = 0;
  constructor() {
    const o: any = {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Jeanette',
      'last_name': 'Penddreth',
      'email': 'jpenddreth0@census.gov',
      'gender': 'Female',
      'ip_address': '26.58.193.2'
    };
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.data.push(o);
      console.log(this.data.length);
      if ( this.count++ === 5) {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }
    }, 1000 * 1);
  }

  data = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Jeanette',
    'last_name': 'Penddreth',
    'email': 'jpenddreth0@census.gov',
    'gender': 'Female',
    'ip_address': '26.58.193.2'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Giavani',
    'last_name': 'Frediani',
    'email': 'gfrediani1@senate.gov',
    'gender': 'Male',
    'ip_address': '229.179.4.212'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Noell',
    'last_name': 'Bea',
    'email': 'nbea2@imageshack.us',
    'gender': 'Female',
    'ip_address': '180.66.162.255'
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Willard',
    'last_name': 'Valek',
    'email': 'wvalek3@vk.com',
    'gender': 'Male',
    'ip_address': '67.76.188.26'
  }];
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-ng-table [data]="data"></app-ng-table>
```

How can I make the component update when `@Input` changes?

**UPDATE:** I have created a plunkr demonstrating this: https://plnkr.co/edit/szz1SNooQ1vIZhnFgiys?p=preview

Comment: try an observable of input by referring to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467336/observable-of-input-property/44467942#44467942)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TimHovius stated, angular is only doing a reference check. Since you are pushing to the same array, the ng-table.component is not detecting a change (the reference to the input is still the same). One thing you can do is to create a shallow copy of the array.

```
addItem(): void {
    this.data.push(this.data[this.data.length-1]);
    // create shallow copy of array, since this is a new array (and new reference) ngOnChanges hook of the ng-table.component will fire
    this.data = this.data.slice(0);
}
```

Now ng-table.component will detect that the input has changed and fire ngOnChanges

Here is a plunkr demoing this (https://plnkr.co/edit/2tdMEA9PLc2TEL4Gy4Lp?p=preview)

Comment: @cyberpirate92 forgot to add my plnkr

Comment: Thanks @LLai, shallow copying works.
I was wondering if there is any other way where I don't have to shallow copy in the parent component? I wonder how `kendo-grid` does it without an explicit shallow copy.

Comment: @cyberpirate92 I'm not familiar with kendo-grid, but it is probably not relying on the ngOnChanges hook. (https://plnkr.co/edit/G1dlSJqtcJ9NX7F44zaz?p=preview) In this plunkr you can see the child component does pick up changes in the ngFor. But in your case, since you have the `extractRowsAndColumns` method in your ngOnChanges hook, you are needing that to run.

Answer (score 4):

Just make your @Input() two-way binding...

```
_data;
@Input() set data(val) {
  this._data = val;
}
get data() {
  return this._data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem before; the `ngOnChanges` method listens only to changes on datatypes `==!` array.

Explanation ([ngOnChanges not firing for nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object/34799257#34799257)):

> During change detection, when Angular checks components' input
>   properties for change, it uses (essentially) === for dirty checking.
>   For arrays, this means the array references (only) are dirty checked.
>   Since the rawLapsData array reference isn't changing, ngOnChanges()
>   will not be called.

Comment: You are right, the data in the child is indeed getting updated, but the `ngOnChanges` event is not getting fired. I tried logging the data in the child component using `setInterval` and I could see it getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

as a simple solution to your problem , you can detect `@Input` changes in `ngOnChanges` like this :

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {   
   for (let propName in changes) {
      // when your @Input value is changed  
      if(propName === "yourInputName"){
         // update the component here 
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have implemented `OnChanges`, but it's not working.

Comment: what u want : if `data`'s value changed you update the component by calling the method `extractRowsAndColumns` with the new `data` , am i right ?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want

Comment: is there any errors ? , what happens exactly when you implemented my answer ?

Comment: I couldn't find any errors in the debug console, the table doesn't get updated ( the new rows are not getting added).

Comment: did you tried to log the data to verify if it's not empty ?

Comment: Yes, when `setInterval` is called, the `data` in `app.component` is getting upated, but not in `ng-table.component`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign new object to it. Mostly can be done by `Object.assign`

In your example, you just need to change few line and rest will work smooth.

```
...
let data:[] = this.data;
data.push(o);
this.data = Object.assign([], data);
...
```