# Updating Input Array

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a parent component which includes a child component. The parent component passes an array to the child. Within the child component I can do several operation on this array. I always create a new array to set the array so everything is updated in the UI. But when I access this array in the parent component, it is not updated at all.

How can I fix this?

Here is a stackblitz for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5yah4v

Comment: Here is a little stackblitz @ChellappanV https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5yah4v

Comment: You must use https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event Output (the EventEmiter is type of EventEmiter<any[]>)

Comment: what do you want to achive your example working fine

Comment: @ChellappanV the first stackblitz was a rudimental demo version. In my real application I am using ag-grid for my list. This seems to be the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfunyh

Answer (score 2):

You can either not create a copy of the array itself because that changes the reference to the old array and hence any operations on the new array would have no result on the old / passed array.

Or

If you want to limit the operations in the child component and want to send the data only after click of a button, like say 'Save' button, then you may use @Output property to send the array in your child component to the parent component. The @Output works just like emitting events.

Comment: The first option is my choice. But I have to pass a new instance, else it is not recognized by changedetection @Ankit Sharma

Comment: @MeMeMax Change detection doesn't work? can you reproduce it in a stackblitz?
Seems to work fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsgbw3?file=src/app/picklist/picklist.component.ts

Comment: @cyberpirate92 thanks for your comment. I found that it´s due to the list component, which I use. I used <ul> only for demo purposes. In my real application I use ag-grid https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsgbw3

Comment: Sorry this is the correct stackblitz for my comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfunyh

Answer (score 0):

why you don't just use services for this

1- create new service and add it in `app.module.ts`

2- in service file add your array and add a method that when it fire update the array by push new value to it.

3- you can access to this service in both components whether retrieve the array or push new value to it

4- both components will get the same instance of the service which is the same array

Answer (score 0):

The problem: You are mutating an array in the child component and the grids aren't getting notified of the changes, the grid seems to be checking ONLY for reference changes. (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830843/2526437) answer for a similar problem)

You have two options

Option 1 - Use a `EventEmitter` to notify parent of changes

Emit an event when the data changes.

```
@Output()
onDataChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

moveToTarget() {
    this.targetList.push(this.sourceList.splice(0, 1)[0]);
    console.log('this.targetList');
    console.log(this.targetList);
    console.log('this.sourceList');
    console.log(this.sourceList);
    this.onDataChanged.emit();   // <---
}
```

Then in the parent component, refresh the array upon receiving the event

```
<app-picklist [sourceList]="sourceFunction" [targetList]="targetFunction" 
(onDataChanged)="refresh()"></app-picklist>

public refresh() {
    this.sourceFunction = [...this.sourceFunction];
    this.targetFunction = [...this.targetFunction];
}
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btgafk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Option 2 - Create a shared data service and make use of `Observable`/`BehaviorSubject`.